# How to update the `$scope` object from `directive` controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, prototypal-inheritance

I am trying to update the `$scope` object from controller, But it's not updating. but in console i am getting updated status.

here is my code :

```
var galleryMenu = ['$route', function ($route) {

    return {

        scope : true,

        replace : true,

        template : function () {

            var page = $route.current.className || 'home';

            return galleryMenuItem(page);

        },

        controller : function ($scope, $element) {

            $scope.galleryProject = function () {

                $scope.galleryShow = !$scope.galleryShow;
                console.log($scope.galleryShow) //gives me true, but `DOM` not updating.

            }


        }

    }

}];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your directive is using `scope: true` that means you have create a scope which is prototypically inherited from parent scope.

Then your `galleryShow` object should follow [**`dot rule`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs)

```
$scope.model = {};
$scope.model.galleryShow = 'something';
```

So then in your directive you could get `$scope.model` object by prototypal inheritance and you could change it by `$scope.model.galleryShow` will change parent scope.

**Directive Controller**

```
controller : function ($scope, $element) {
     $scope.galleryProject = function () {
         $scope.model.galleryShow = !$scope.galleryShow;
         console.log($scope.model.galleryShow) //gives me true, but `DOM` not updating.
     }
  }
```

Comment: Ok, if I give `scope:false`, is that possible to update in parent scope?

Comment: Yes, this is working. and i need to append a `directive to DOM with ng-repeat` - how to do that?

Comment: yes, works. can you help me to append a `directive to DOM` with `ng-repeat`? is it possible to do from controller or i need to use `link` method here?

Comment: @3gwebtrain to changes in a directive which I suggested then put that directive on `ng-repeat` DOM.. should work..

Comment: Actually using this directive I am showing a `gallery` now gallery has not element. i would like to create elements by `ng-repeat`, that means when the `gallery` div on `visible` the `directive` inside automatically works?

Comment: yes..it should work..Bit confused with what you are saying..could you elaborate more on it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81682/discussion-between-3gwebtrain-and-pankajparkar).

Comment: I have a `gallery` div. inside the div i have 3 directives. when the page is `home` i want to run the `page-gallery` directive. in case page is `service` i need to run the `server-gallery` directive - so how to handle that?

Comment: at present, my gallery is shows when the `galleryShow` is `true`. again i need to insist the gallery to run only `home-gallery` - if i am not clear please post your question.

Comment: @3gwebtrain could you come on chat?